# Why is Django template not responding to static files?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

It is exactly how it sounds. My main goal is to make the css file work with django template so I can design my templates.

Yesterday I tried and initially my folder structure was wrong. I placed static folder in myapp folder. Didn't work. I tried putting it in templates folder. It only worked when I had 2 static folders both in myapp and templates folder. Realized it isn't a working solution.

I placed a single static folder with a css file in it in mysite folder, at the same level with myapp folder and everything seemed to work. Satisfied I left at that.

Today I came back to it and it stopped working. It seems to be frozen. Not responding to the new codes. Old colors are showing but new colors aren't, which is odd. Tried changing the old colors, it won't change. Literally my css file has a class name .intro where I changed the color from purple to red, my template still showing purple which I set yesterday.

My template shows no error and all the texts and divs I am adding are updating with no issue.Kind of lost where I may have gone wrong. Certainly don't want to work with 2/3 same css file and static folder if I can help it.

Here are some codes.

My folder structure-

[image]

Everytime I update the css and refresh the template my console is showing some kind of error, here they are-

[image]

Settings.py file seems correct. Here is the relevant part-

```
import os 

SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

...
...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),

)

STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

my base.html -

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'ok.css' %}"/>
    
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    <h2 class="ok">This is a test</h2>
    <div class="solved">This took a while!</div>
    <div class="container">Didn't work on the other site!</div>
    {% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

and test.html -

```html
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h2 class="again">Content for My App</h2>
    <p class="intro">Stuff etc etc.</p>
    <p class="ok">write some more</p>

    <div class="container">This should work</div>
{% endblock %}
```

URLs.py even though I think I am doing ok there -

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('base/', views.ok, name='base'),
    path('test/', views.test, name='test')
]
```

And finally views.py , another page I don't think have any issues -

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html')

def ok(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/base.html')

def test(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/test.html')
```

If you can spot anything kindly let me know. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you can try to hard reset your browser (I think it's CTRL + Shift + R on Chrome). It might just cache the styles.

Comment: Thanks reppon for your answer. After I made this post, gave it a little break and it started working again. So it definitely has to do with cache/cookies etc. If it get stuck again I will try your method. thanks again.